# How can we create configurable product in ubercart?

Tags: 7, ubercart, search

I am creating an e-commerce website using [ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart) and Drupal 7. I have created attribute size and color for the product from the  "Administration » Store » Products" and assigned to product.

I have also used [search api](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) and [facet api](https://drupal.org/project/facetapi) module to generate facet search. I have created a views page to display product listing of search index product and showing facet block in that page.

Now, the problem is that I want to display product attribute as filter in the above product listing page. I have searched on google but did not find any solution for that.

Can any one suggest me?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had this problem,

1. I would have created taxonomy terms corresponding to the attributes
2. The taxonomy terms can be used as search filters, rather than hacking the uc_attributes.

or

1. If views is used to display the products, then add filters in the views as product attributes.
2. The taxonomy terms can also be used in views to filter the products.

Comment: I was also thinking the same. But, how would you display the attribute (taxonomy) in add to cart form and other functionality of attribute.

Comment: Apart from ubercart attributes, you need to have taxonomy terms. If you have 5 attributes you need to create 5 terms.

Comment: You mean, we need to create taxonomy term and also assign attribute to product. I think, there should be some relationship between attribute and taxonomy, so If  we change taxonomy, it should reflect attribute.